# Loading huge Text file in UITextview crashes

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I want to update a huge text file in UITextView. But the device just hangs or crashes some times. The text file size is 4MB.

The UITextView is been added from Interface Builder.

I am loading the file from document directory.
Below is the code for loading the text file:-

```
NSError *err = nil;
txtView.text =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:documentPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

---

As I want to edit the file I cannot load it in WebView which is much faster and it works properly.

Is there any way were I can only partially load the text File(one page at a time) so it doesn't take much time to load or some other way to load the whole file properly ?

Any hint in right direction  would be highly appreciated.
.

Comment: can anyone give me some hint in right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a nasty problem, because you would have to measure how much text has to fit exactly in one page. You could try and play around with the UIScrollView-properties and delegate methods of the textview (like contentOffset), but I would not recommend it.

Personally, I would try to divide the text content into multiple pages (multiple NSStrings) and then use two buttons "next", "previous" to switch between pages within the text view.

Comment: I use the "Previous", "next" logic but it seems for large file it is difficult for user to do this. can we get some open source text file editor

Comment: I tried to put UISlider as scroller but it seems the logic to implement it is quite complex. Can anyone give some hint on that direction

Answer (score -3):

Store each line of your data in an Array and use array as data source of UITableView, rest of the things will be handled by UItableview