# What is the max amount of data UITextView will hold before crashing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have a text file that that can get pretty big and I am trying to load into a UITextView.  It crashes everytime so I'm guessing it has to do with exceeding the amount the UITextView can hold.

This question says to paginate it: [Loading huge Text file in UITextview crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131412/loading-huge-text-file-in-uitextview-crashes)

I just want to tell the user when it's too big to just display a dialog box to tell them to download it from iTunes (I have file sharing enabled on my app).  But what is the max (exact, or ballpark I guess) amount of data that the UITextView can hold before crashing?

Comment: I don't think it's a documenter number which means that it probably isn't the same number every time. This also means that it could change on different hardware and different OS versions.

Comment: I'm thinking it has to be based on memory size (which is hardware based).  But I'm just wondering if there's a way to programmatically find this undocumented number (or within the range of it).